# modify styleClass of a p:commandButton conditionally in primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

I would like to modify the style class of a p:commandButton in primefaces conditionally, like this:

```
 <p:commandButton  value="#{file.name}"  styleClass="#{file.statut == 0 ? 'normalClass' : 'strikeThroughClass'}">
```

It works OK for the normal

```
outputText
```

but does not seem to work on the

```
 p:commandButton
```

Could you give me a hand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used

```
 <h:commandButton styleClass="#{dmFile.statut == 0 ? 'normalClass' : 'strikeThroughClass'}     ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"  value="#{dmFile.name}">
</h:commandButton>
```

And in css

```
.ui-button.strikeThroughClass{
 text-decoration:line-through!important;
}
```